# Shortcut icon not showing in deployed website - Next js

Tags: next.js

It will display the icon in develop mode but when I deploy the project . it wont show me the icon

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
```

my shortcut file is in :

```
/public/images/favicon.ico
```